# Divs side by side

Tags: css, html, sidebar

I'm having some issues by placing 3 divs on the left side... and 1 on the right...
It works perfect if there is only 1 div on each side...

I have a news section... That creates a new div for each news there is.

I will get 5 of these per page...(with more than 1... The div on the right side... will get pushed down....)

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
<div id="NewsPageContent">
THIS STUFF
</div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<?php endforeach ?>
```

All the code:

```
<div id="boxes">
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
<div id="NewsPageContent">
THIS STUFF
</div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<?php endforeach ?>

<div id="PlayersOnline">
<h2>Players Online</h2><hr />
<div id="heads">
This is the div to the right
</div><!--End heads-->
</div><!--End PlayerOnline-->
<div id="clear"></div>
</div><!--End boxes-->
```

css:

```
#boxes{
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   clear:both;
   margin-top: 10px;
}

#NewsPageContent {
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    width: 63%;
    background: #fefefe;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    color: #7c7c7c;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a7a6a6; 
}

#PlayersOnline{
    float:right;
    width: 32%;
    background: #fefefe;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    min-height: 350px;
    color: #7c7c7c;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a7a6a6;
}
```

EDIT:
The HTML from my browser:

```
<div id="boxes">
<div class="NewsPageContent">
                       <div id="news_title">
            <h3>HomieCraft</h3><hr />
            <div id="newsbuttons" style="float: right; font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://10.0.0.88/news/article/15">Read</a> | <a href="#">Comment(6)</a></div>
                <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">Published 26-04-2013 23:39 by GudfareN </p>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 6px;" id="news_text">
               <p> HomieCraft awwwwyeeeee</p>
            </div>
            </div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<div class="NewsPageContent">
                       <div id="news_title">
            <h3>HomieCraft</h3><hr />
            <div id="newsbuttons" style="float: right; font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://10.0.0.88/news/article/14">Read</a> | <a href="#">Comment(6)</a></div>
                <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">Published 26-04-2013 23:39 by GudfareN </p>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 6px;" id="news_text">
               <p> HomieCraft awwwwyeeeee</p>
            </div>
            </div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<div class="NewsPageContent">
                       <div id="news_title">
            <h3>HomieCraft</h3><hr />
            <div id="newsbuttons" style="float: right; font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://10.0.0.88/news/article/13">Read</a> | <a href="#">Comment(6)</a></div>
                <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">Published 26-04-2013 23:39 by GudfareN </p>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 6px;" id="news_text">
               <p> HomieCraft awwwwyeeeee</p>
            </div>
            </div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<div class="NewsPageContent">
                       <div id="news_title">
            <h3>HomieCraft</h3><hr />
            <div id="newsbuttons" style="float: right; font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://10.0.0.88/news/article/12">Read</a> | <a href="#">Comment(6)</a></div>
                <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">Published 26-04-2013 23:39 by GudfareN </p>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 6px;" id="news_text">
               <p> HomieCraft awwwwyeeeee</p>
            </div>
            </div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<div class="NewsPageContent">
                       <div id="news_title">
            <h3>HomieCraft</h3><hr />
            <div id="newsbuttons" style="float: right; font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://10.0.0.88/news/article/11">Read</a> | <a href="#">Comment(6)</a></div>
                <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">Published 26-04-2013 23:39 by GudfareN </p>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 6px;" id="news_text">
               <p> HomieCraft awwwwyeeeee</p>
            </div>
            </div><!--End NewsPageContent-->
<div id="PlayersOnline" style="margin-top: 10px;">
<h2>Players Online</h2><hr />
<div id="heads">
</div><!--End heads-->
</div><!--End PlayerOnline-->
<div id="clear"></div>
</div><!--End boxes-->
```

Comment: Inside the `foreach` you're creating several divs with the same `id`. use `class` instead

Comment: You're creating div's with an id in a foreach loop. This will give you validation errors...

Comment: Hi Stian, perhaps as this is a html problem it may help if you copy the html it produces in your browser, and show us that, instead of showing us the logic that creates the html, as we don't have the rest of your logic to see what it produces.

Comment: Added the HTML in my post now.. That was produced in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position your `PlayersOnline` absolute and give a relative position to your `#boxes`.
Then put `right: 5px;` on your `PlayersOnline` div and here's what you get.

http://jsfiddle.net/24LtW/

Also note you should not give the `NewsPageContent` an id, but a `class` attribute.

Comment: Well yes this works... But then the players online box won't resize the page... When i gets longer than "NewsPageContent"...

Comment: Is your PlayersOnline always the same height? if so you can just set the height attribute of the boxes div. If not you can wrap your news boxes with a div and float that one left and leave it like it was initially

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the html you pasted, produced what I think it is you wanted...

code at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/kuh6r/)

```
.NewsPageContent /*now a class not id as suggested in comments*/
```

and...

```
<div id="PlayersOnline"> is placed above <div class="NewsPageContent">
```

Basically, I moved your 'floating to the right' box to the top of the html, above the 'floating to the left' boxes. If the screen width is too short the boxes will misalign themselves on top of one another, but if you place all your html into a fixed width div the width of your intended design, the div's should never 'stack' themselves.

I also, changed your 'id' to a 'class' where required as pointed out @Fabrizio

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/kuh6r/1/ - sets the width of '#boxes' to 950px (fixed width) so the boxes align as you'd like